# How to save label content

Tags: swift, database, save, label

in my TodoList I have a label that when add something in the Todo, show the date the day.

How can I save it? cause when I open my app I have always the date and time of when I open it.

Here is the code of the label with the date:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var Data: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        Data.text = String(describing: DateFormatter())

        UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Data")

        let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm a"
        Data.text = dataFormatter.string(from: .init())

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move code inside `setSelected` to `awakeFromNib`

also i expect this `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Data")` to return a value , so someWhere you should have `UserDefaults.standard.set(value:"----Any value", forKey: "Data")`

```
 guard let res =  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Data")  as? Date else { return }
 let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dataFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm a"
 Data.text = dataFormatter.string(from:res)
```

For sett

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "Data")
```

---

```
@IBOutlet weak var Data: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "Data") // this line need to be placed where you need to store the date
    guard let storedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Data") as? Date  else { return } // here you read the stored date
    let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy H:mm a"
    Data.text = dataFormatter.string(from:storedDate)

}
```

Comment: Hey I tried as you said but the app crash...this is the code.   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        guard (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Data")  as? Data) != nil else { return }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Data, forKey: "Data")
        let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy H:mm a"
        Data.text = dataFormatter.string(from: .init())
        
        
    }

Comment: @Matteo what crash share it

Comment: Thats the error.............Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object <UILabel: 0x7f80cbe659a0; frame = (352 11; 42 47); text = 'Label'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x6000003b8320>> for key Data'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: you try to save the label itself , you need `UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "Data")` verify it's not `UserDefaults.standard.set(Data, forKey: "Data")`

Comment: Okay now is not crashing, but I don't have time time and the date, just the name "label"

Comment: That's my code        @IBOutlet weak var Data: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib().      What you mean for store and read?
        
        guard (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Data")  as? Data) != nil else { return }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "Data")
        let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy H:mm a"
        Data.text = dataFormatter.string(from: .init())
        
        
    }

Comment: Okay and after edit how can I show you...sorry I'm slow?.....In the TodoList I'm using CoreData maybe is for this is not saving?....anyway why I have the name "label"....what do you think?

Comment: then this not the correct way as the all labels will have same content , you need to 
        read the store data in viewDidLoad of the vc then reload the table

Comment: How can I read the store data? Anyway if I put the label in a TableView controller it can work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UserDefaults.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value: Any?, forKey: String)
```

So, whenever you want to save you could do

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value: YourValue, forKey: "Data")
```

Answer (score 0):

First create global `lazy` variable for your `DateFormatter` since you don't want to create new one every time you need to set text.

```
lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm a"
    return formatter
}()
```

then you can set `text` of label like this (rename outlet for `UILabel` to start with small capital letter)

```
data.text = dateFormatter.string(from: yourDate)
```

---

Now for manipulating with `Date` object with `UserDefaults`

**Saving:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(yourDate, forKey: "date")
```

**Getting:**

```
if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "date") as? Date {
    ... // here you can use `date` of type `Date`
}
```

---

One advice at the end. Since you're using `UITableViewCell`, I suppose that you have more then one `Date` object saved in `UserDefaults`. I would recommend you to start using some database like *Core Data* or *Realm*.